# How to get odd or even numbers in C# with a user input?

Tags: c#

I am very new to C# and have been set a task to make a program that asks for a user input of a number and then says if that number is odd or even. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi... Please see this first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which part of that task is a problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because determing odd or even numbers is a trivial mathematical problem that has already been addressed on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to figure how to check if a number is odd or even. **How can do, you ask?**
You may not have learned this yet, but [modulus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) is the simplest way to do it. It uses the character `%` and it basically acts as a division, but instead of telling what value each parts of the division equals, it tells you what is **left** from the division. Coming from that, you know that if the number divided by `% 2` is 0, your number is even because there is nothing left. `4 / 2 = 2` vs `4 % 2 = 0`

**My example here is not the shortest or fastest, but is easier to understand for a beginner**

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your number : ");
string number = Console.ReadLine();
Int32.Parse(number);

if(number % 2 == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your number is even.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your number is odd.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [remainder (modulus) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-).

An example:

```
int userInput = // get your input
bool isEven = userInput % 2 == 0;
```

An even number will have a remainder of 0 when divided by 2.

Answer (score 0):

In one line

```
Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) % 2 == 0 ? "even":"odd");
```